# Cordova 3.4 contact plugin not working?

Tags: cordova, contacts

Is anyone else having trouble getting the contact plugin to work in cordova 3.4?

I get this error, no matter what I do: ReferenceError: ContactFindOptions is not defined

All other plugins are working fine. I am working with IOS only.

I am just using the basic example from the docs, when device is ready:

```
var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter   = "Milo";
        options.multiple = true;
        var fields       = ["displayName", "name"];
        navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

Comment: You included the plugin correctly and updated the config.xml file?

Comment: Yes. Cordova adds the reference in the config automatically, when installed via commandline. It would also make a reference error in the xcode console, if the plugin was not initialized in the config.

Comment: And it looks similar to the e.g. Battery plugin, which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please see my below instructions:

First, You should check (Contact) installed plugin via terminal properly

> $ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts

Second, You should check your entry is mention in config.xml properly which is looks like below:- 

> <feature name="Contacts">
>         <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
>     </feature>

Third, please also check you mention cordova.js in html 

Thanks,
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are incorrectly ordered. Check:

```
navigator.contacts.find(onSuccess, onError, fields, options);
```